# Side effect of $injector.get()? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm trying to decorate $log with a service that depends on $http and it's raising a circular dependency error. Some fixes point to get my factory through $injector.get('myService'), so DI of myService is delayed and doesn't provoke the error.

Anyways, whether it's delayed or not, there's a circular dependency and I'm trying to guess what can go wrong doing this, as I though $injector.get is an anti-pattern.

So, what side effect / bug can produce avoiding circular dependency injection using $inject.get()?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense without actual code. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A fiddle/plunk that can replicate the problem will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my previous project we tried to implement the same but faced with the circular dependency but we came up with a different solution in order to handle this error.

> 1.what side effect / bug can produce avoiding circular dependency injection using $inject.get()?

while coming to the  circular dependency is always the sign of **mixing of concerns** . There is a better example explaining this phenomenon by [Miško Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) on his awesome blog.

In short for answering your this **(side effect / bug can produce)** part of question :  you probably will have a third service hidden somewhere, which is the only part of your code really needed by the two others , so if any error occurred in that hidden service, it may not provoke error , this might be the side effect you probably would be facing .

To overcome this unhandled behaviour and If you are willing to try another solution by adding `Jquery` and logging the error using `Ajax` , i can give you the angular module which we implemented for logging error without causing circular dependency .